# How to apply large external CSS files to only a specific region on the page - CSS Preprocessor failing

Tags: css, less

I have two very large external stylesheets that I want to pull into my WordPress site. I want their styles to only be applied to content in a div with the ID of "pattern" - they should not affect any other content.

I attempted to do this using PHP and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) as follows.

In the head of my document, I have:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/less">
            #pattern {
                    <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedSkin.css'); ?> 
                    <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedLess.css'); ?>
                    p {color:#F00;}
            }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/less.js"></script>
```

When I comment out the two file_get_contents lines, LESS successfully processes the "p {color:#F00;} line and applies it to content inside the #pattern div.

However when I attempt to pull in those two stylesheets, I get an error in less.js: [image: less.js failed]

I'm not sure what the error is, but my guess is that the CSS files (http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedSkin.css , http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedLess.css) are too large for LESS to handle. How else can I achieve this? Also, note that those two CSS files will be updated regularly, and I want to pull in the most recent changes, so I want to link to the live files.

Answer (score 1):

You should include these with:

```
<style scoped >@import:url(style.css);</style>
```

inside the container where you want it applied.
BUT, Unfortunatelly, it's not working well yet. it applies to all page in most browser.
example to test from browsers to browsers : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/kGzLh

You'll need an heavier selector to strictly applie it to one zone (named by id for instance).

you may break this files into smaller

Comment: I actually tried using the HTML5 "scoped" attribute on the style tag similar to what you suggested AND using [this jQuery polyfill](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) to make current browsers respect the "scoped" attribute. The jQuery polyfill moved the CSS inline into the HTML elements, but they did not render that CSS at all. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Too bad, sorry for you (wich polyfill do you use ? )

Comment: it's a hyperlink in the first comment https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has to do with file size, but file type.

### Possibly, This is What You Want

You are bringing in what appears to be already compiled css (your file names end in `.css`), not actual `.less` files. I'm assuming these are precomplied css from less. If that is the case, then you probably just need to change your parameter on your `style` tag, as as you are not really even importing less. So... `type="text/less"` is changed here:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
   #pattern {
      <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedSkin.css'); ?> 
      <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedLess.css'); ?>
      p {color:#F00;}
   }
</style>
```

### However, This May Be More Your Desire and Real Issue

If you actually do want them to be LESS code at this point (or if the two files do contain LESS code, and thus are invalid CSS), then you need to be importing `.less` files, so the two files need that extension instead, like so:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/less">
   #pattern {
      <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedSkin.less'); ?> 
      <?php echo file_get_contents('http://ace.staging.managebuilding.com/Manager/css/combinedLess.less'); ?>
      p {color:#F00;}
   }
</style>
```

This is because LESS does not actually process css files. "[If you want to import a CSS file, and don’t want LESS to process it, just use the .css extension.](http://www.lesscss.org/#-importing)"

Comment: Thanks. I tried saving the two CSS files locally, changing the extensions to .less, and linking them as in your second example. LESS.js turned the <style> tag containing the styles into a completely empty <style> tag as shown at http://i.imgur.com/s9x1Tm0.png . This was the same result I was getting earlier.

Comment: Your screen shot picture shows that the `type` of that empty tag is `text/css`, but note in my second example that the `type` is `text/less`. Try that.

Comment: "text/less" is what I put in the <style> tag, but LESS.js converts the type to "text/css".

Comment: Oh, of course! I would not think file length would be the issue, but have you tried a "short" file to test that? Also, have you looked at the code where the compressor failed (just after the `@media all and` in your attached image) to see if there is a funky whitespace character or something there that might cause the compressor to choke?

Comment: Thanks. I think this may be on the right track because there are a couple of linebreaks and a comment at that point interrupting the media query (just after the `@media all and`). I removed the linebreaks and comments in the local files but had the same problem when referencing those local files (tried both as .css and .less extensions). I'll look into it further with our developers who are more familiar with what's in those stylesheets.